# How do I introduce the equivalent of a foreign key into a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a project that has two collections: `cafes` to store information about various Cafes, and `reviews` to store information about cafe reviews, which is structured as follows:

```
Database
|
+--cafes (collection)
      +-- _id:5ffb7a6bf32d1b27ac8474d9
          cafeName:"Customs Coffee
          photoURL:"https://*******
+--reviews (collection)
      +--_id:5ffb95b75624dd13d825ea5e
          userName:"Josh"
          stars:"4"
           title:"Second review of customs coffee"
          photo:"photoURL.com"
          blurb: "this is the blurb for the second review of customs"
          cafe:"Customs Coffee"
          createdAt:2021-01-11T00:03:03.842+00:00
```

I want each review document within the `reviews` collection to **also** contain the id of the cafe that the review is about- any suggestions on how I can do that? So for example, the review document as shown above would ideally look like this:

```
          id:5ffb95b75624dd13d825ea5e
          userName:"Josh"
          stars:"4"
           title:"Second review of customs coffee"
          photo:"photoURL.com"
          blurb: "this is the blurb for the second review of customs"
          cafe:"Customs Coffee"
          **cafeId:5ffb7a6bf32d1b27ac8474d9**
          createdAt:2021-01-11T00:03:03.842+00:00
```

Here's the Schema for the `cafes` and `reviews` collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const cafeSchema = new Schema({
    cafeName:String,
    photoURL:String,
}, {timestamps:true})

cafeSchema.virtual('reviews', {
    ref: 'Review',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'cafe'
});

const Cafe = mongoose.model('cafes', cafeSchema)

module.exports = Cafe
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const reviewSchema = new Schema({
    userName:String,
    stars:String,
    title:String,
    photo:String,
    blurb:String,
    cafeName:String,
    cafe: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Cafe'
    }
}, {timestamps:true})

const Review = mongoose.model('reviews', reviewSchema)

module.exports = Review
```

Comment: do you have a special reason for using  `populating virtual` in CafeSchema? beacuse for your issue don't need to create a `cafeSchema.virtual`